# Junit for protected method returning new instances

Tags: protected, easymock

How to write junit in easyMock for this code snippet

```
protected void fireMonitor(BusMessage busMessage) {
    String distCode = getDistCode();    
    if (distCode.equals("OMP")) {
        new Monitor(hotelRateFeed.getHostCode();
    } 
}
```

We need to validate the Monitor generated here. Can anyone please help me to solve?

Comment: to create a test, you have to ask yourself "what is the behavior of this method", and test this behavior. in your example, we have to know what does "new Monitor"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually mock and set expectation for new operator as well using PowerMock.

```
   Monitor monitor= PowerMock.createMock(Monitor.class);
    PowerMock.expectNew(Monitor.class, <hostcode parameter>).andReturn(monitor).once();
    PowerMock.replayAll(monitor);
    PowerMock.verify(monitor);
```

This way, you can verify if object is getting created once. Hope it helps